# Help me to parse

Tags: iphone, ios4

I'm using a class written by a **[blogger](http://troybrant.net/blog/)** that takes an XML string and spits out a NSDictionary.

It's beautiful...works perfectly, but my  tag is not parsed. since in that class he has used like below

```
NSString *const kXMLReaderTextNodeKey = @"text";

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    // Update the parent dict with text info
    NSMutableDictionary *dictInProgress = [dictionaryStack lastObject];

    // Set the text property
    if ([textInProgress length] > 0)
    {
        [dictInProgress setObject:textInProgress forKey:kXMLReaderTextNodeKey];



        // Reset the text
        [textInProgress release];
        textInProgress = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }

    // Pop the current dict
    [dictionaryStack removeLastObject]; }
```

Kindly please help me out how to fix this...

Thanks a lot

Comment: Post your xml too. How to judge what is the problem in above code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note: Make sure the XML you’re parsing doesn’t contain a field named “text”! You can change it to a non-conflicting name by editing the kXMLReaderTextNodeKey constant at the top of XMLReader.m.**

This is there in the BLOGGER Website. In XMLReader.m file you have `NSString *const kXMLReaderTextNodeKey = @"text";` which conflicts with your xml tag `<text>` so either change your xml field tag from `<text>` to anything else or

change `NSString *const kXMLReaderTextNodeKey = @"text";`

to `NSString *const kXMLReaderTextNodeKey = @"textdata";`

After that use NSDictionary as routine code. Check it out and let me know.

Comment: its crashing after changing as NSString *const kXMLReaderTextNodeKey = @"textdata";Any helps pls

Comment: -[NSNull stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1593dc8
2011-07-02 14:43:25.716 Zapd[6908:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1593dc8' this is the error log i get

Comment: @barbgal Sorry but you need to add code for your parsing now. How do you take output from NSDictionary ? let say how do you print value for any tag ? I have tried changing that value and I am getting NSDictionary successfully.

Comment: @barbgal plz paste full code of accessing dictionary in above in your answer.

Comment: @barbgal Since you've changed the `text` key to `textdata`, you will have to alter the rest of the code to access the content of a tag using `textdata` rather than `text`. If your XML was the same was the one you edited out. You must access the content using `created_on.textdata` and I don't think its an array, is it?

Comment: Yes. i got it to worked but i am having problem when only one items is found.when one items is found i print count it shows me as 6.so my app crashes.if i have more than one, there were no problem at all. why this happening?